# Tab crashes after validating form (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I'm new to JavaScript and I've tried to write a simple validator for an html form, but it crashes in most cases. After clicking on "Submit" button, page becomes unresponsive and sometimes I even can't close it.

Email validator seems to work properly, but name validator and zip code validator often crash, even when everything is fine.

Please, help!

**My JS code and HTML form**

```js
var myForm    = document.forms.myForm;
var message   = document.getElementById("messageField");


myForm.onsubmit = function()
{
    if (emailValidator() == false || nameValidator() == false || zipCodeValidator() == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        message.innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
};


function emailValidator()
{
    if (myForm.email.value.indexOf("@") == -1 || myForm.email.value.indexOf("@") == 0 || myForm.email.value.indexOf("@") == myForm.email.value.length - 1 || myForm.email.value.indexOf("@") != myForm.email.value.lastIndexOf("@"))
    {
        console.log("Invalid email error!");
        message.innerHTML = "Your email is incorrect!";
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function nameValidator()
{
    // var firstNameString = String(myForm.firstName.value);
    // var lastNameString  = String(myForm.lastName.value);

    for (var i = 0; String(myForm.firstName.value).length; i++)
    {
        if (!isNaN(String(myForm.firstName.value)[i]))
        {
            console.log("Invalid first name!");
            message.innerHTML = "Your first name is incorrect!";
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; String(myForm.lastName.value).length; i++)
    {
        if (!isNaN(String(myForm.lastName.value)[i]))
        {
            console.log("Invalid last name!");
            message.innerHTML = "Your last name is incorrect!";
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function zipCodeValidator()
{
    var zipCodeString = String(myForm.zipCode.value);

    if (zipCodeString.length != 5)
    {
        console.log("Invalid zip code!");
        message.innerHTML = "Your zip code is incorrect!";
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (isNaN(zipCodeString[i]))
        {
            console.log("Invalid zip code!");
            message.innerHTML = "Your zip code is incorrect!";
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="#" method="#">
            <p>First name</p>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" required/>
            <p>Last name</p>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" required/>
            <p>ZIP code</p>
            <input type="text" name="zipCode" required/>
            <p>Email</p>
            <input type="text" name="email" required/>
            <p><input type="reset"/> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
        </form>
        <div id="messageField" style="color: red"></div>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dd92y2vh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

In function `nameValidator()` you have 2 typos in loops' condition checks, namely you miss `i <` in the beginning. The way it is right now, your condition checks are numbers (lengths of name fields) which JS treats as true (`Boolean(7) === true`) and as such you get stuck in an infinite loop.

### Solution

- Replace `String(myForm.firstName.value).length` with `i < myForm.firstName.value.length`
- Replace `String(myForm.lastName.value).length` with `i < myForm.lastName.value.length`

#### Correct loop declarations

After you implement above solution your loop declarations should look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myForm.lastName.value.length; i++)
for (var i = 0; i < myForm.lastName.value.length; i++)
```

- [Working code](https://jsfiddle.net/zwb6onjs/) forked from yours.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical error in below peace of code.

```
for (var i = 0; String(myForm.firstName.value).length; i++)
{
    if (!isNaN(String(myForm.firstName.value)[i]))
    {
        console.log("Invalid first name!");
        message.innerHTML = "Your first name is incorrect!";
        return false;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; String(myForm.lastName.value).length; i++)
{
    if (!isNaN(String(myForm.lastName.value)[i]))
    {
        console.log("Invalid last name!");
        message.innerHTML = "Your last name is incorrect!";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just see the loop breaking condition. How you have written.

```
for (var i = 0; **String(myForm.firstName.value).length**; i++)
```

lets say if firstname value is **"John"** then it's length would be 4 and loop breaking condition always be true. basically it's an infinite loop. I am sure that is what making your page unresponsive. If you change the loop breaking condition it will work.... **Happy coding**